# Issue with permissions of payment gateway library while uploading

Tags: android, permissions

Recently I have published my app to play store which has instamojo payment gateway integrated in it, but it gets rejected due to permission violation policies.
After removing policies from manifest it is still asking for the core functionality of app related sms permission.

here is my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
            tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
                     tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
                  tools:node="remove"
                  android:required="false"/>
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Is your latest build updated on your play store ? It'll take some time to update the policy in play store.

Comment: After removing policies from manifest it is still asking for the core functionality of app related sms permission.
This was the major issue solved this by creating new app with new package name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on [SMS Retriver API]  https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview.

If your app need to read sms for SMS-based user verification / OTP verification please use SMS Retriever API which does not needed any sms permission and your app can still read SMS for OTP verification.

Comment: This is needed i case i have used these permission in my code. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Please mark this right answer so that next time other programmers can reffer it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used instamojo payment getway in app, in case of using instamojo dependencies you can't do anything. for resolve this issue you need to use add instamojo module in your app.Then you can remove SMS permission which is give in instamojo module. These permission not affect your app.

Google recommend that you can't take permission of SMS, that's why google reject your app.
By removing SMS permission you can easily upload APK on play store.